# Pandas: Apply rolling function to compute new column value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to compute a new column Y on each row by checking the 9 previous rows and current row values of column X. Basically the new column Y value on each row will tell us the percentage on values of column X were greater than 1 for previous 10 records including the current record . Below is the code i am using but getting a different result than expected

[EDITED]

```
def count_pcnt(x):
 return ((np.sum(x > 1) / len(x)) * 100.0)

def run():
df = pd.DataFrame(
data={'X': ['8.12', '7.13', '-5.30', '3.21', '4.21', '3.14','8.65', 
            '7.33', '-5.10', '3.01']
      })


df['Y'] = df['X'].rolling(window=10, min_periods=1).apply(lambda x: 
          count_pcnt(x)).apply(int)
```

Expected Result  **[ EDITED ]**

```
     X    Y(%)
0   8.12  100
1   7.13  100
2  -5.30  66.67
3   3.21  75
4   4.21  80
5   3.14  83.33
6   8.65  85.71
7   7.33  87.50
8  -5.10  77.77
9   3.01  80
```

Actual

```
      X    Y
 0   8.12  100
 1   7.13  100
 2  -5.30  0
 3   3.21  0
 4   4.21  0
 5   3.14  0
 6   8.65  0
 7   7.33  0
 8  -5.10  0
 9   3.01  0
```

**UPDATE** I used this option recommended below and it worked. Though there are other options i felt this is much cleaner

```
df['Y'] = df['X'].astype(float)
             .rolling(window=w, min_periods=1)
             .apply(lambda x: (x>1).mean()) * 100
```

if you want to compute column values based on next 10 rows rather than previous 10 rows -  below is the solution (Thanks to **jezrae**l who provided it)

```
df['Y'] = (df['X'].astype(float).iloc[::-1].rolling(window=10, min_periods=1).apply(lambda x: (x>1).mean()) * 100)[::-1]
```

Comment: For the first 9 records, it won't have a window of size 9, which is why you're seeing NaN's. I would imagine either setting them manually, or gradually increasing the window size till it reaches 9.

Comment: Also, your expected result looks wrong. Why should the first record have a value of 80%? It doesn't have any record before it. Why is the second record's value 77%? All of the records before it have an X value greater than 1, so shouldn't it be 100%?

Comment: @HavanAgrawal I believe OP has his values inverted, with the exception of a calc error here and there.

Comment: @HavanAgrawal corrected the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

- first convert column `X` to `float` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html)
- add parameter `min_periods` to [`Series.rolling`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.rolling.html)
- instead custom function use lambda with `(x>1).mean()` with same output

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
data={'X': ['8.12', '7.13', '-5.30', '3.21', '4.21', '3.14','8.65', 
            '7.33', '-5.10', '3.01']
      })
w = 10
df['Y'] = df['X'].astype(float)
                 .rolling(window=w, min_periods=1)
                 .apply(lambda x: (x>1).mean()) * 100
print(df)

      X           Y
0  8.12  100.000000
1  7.13  100.000000
2 -5.30   66.666667
3  3.21   75.000000
4  4.21   80.000000
5  3.14   83.333333
6  8.65   85.714286
7  7.33   87.500000
8 -5.10   77.777778
9  3.01   80.000000
```

Solution with custom function:

```
def count_pcnt(x):
    return ((np.sum(x>1))/ len(x))*100.0

w = 10
df['Y'] = df['X'].astype(float).rolling(window=w, min_periods=1).apply(count_pcnt)
print(df)
       X           Y
0   8.12  100.000000
1   7.13  100.000000
2  -5.30   66.666667
3   3.21   75.000000
4   4.21   80.000000
5   3.14   83.333333
6   8.65   85.714286
7   7.33   87.500000
8  -5.10   77.777778
9   3.01   80.000000
```

EDIT:

Function can be changed by:

```
def count_pcnt(x):
    return ((x>1).sum() / len(x))*100.0
```

or:

```
def count_pcnt(x):
    return (x>1).mean()*100.0
```

Comment: this doesn't work df['Y'] = df['X'].astype(float).rolling(window=10, min_periods=1).apply(count_pcnt)

Comment: Is function correct? Maybe some `()` is problem - can you check it?

Comment: yes function is correct but ouput is same as in the question.  Your first option worked though!

Comment: I add 2 alternatives of function with same output, can you check it how doeas it work?

Comment: function with mean works correct but not the other one

Comment: do you remove `apply(int)` after apply?

Comment: But it should work, maybe some typo only (I hope so)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148713/discussion-between-user845405-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 2):

You may set the `min_periods=1` attribute in [`df.rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html):

```
In [927]: def count_pcnt(x):
     ...:     return ((np.sum(x > 1) / len(x)) * 100.0)
     ...: 

In [930]: df['Y'] = df['X'].astype(np.float64).rolling(window=10, min_periods=1).apply(lambda x: count_pcnt(x))

In [931]: df
Out[931]: 
       X           Y
0   8.12  100.000000
1   7.13  100.000000
2  -5.30   66.666667
3   3.21   75.000000
4   4.21   80.000000
5   3.14   83.333333
6   8.65   85.714286
7   7.33   87.500000
8  -5.10   77.777778
9   3.01   80.000000
```

I've modified your `count_pcnt` function to take into account variable window sizes being passed. I believe this is what you're looking for.

Comment: @COLDSPEED i tried running but i am not getting the correct Y values as you pointed up

Comment: def count_pcnt(x):
  return ((np.sum(x > 1) / len(x)) * 100.0)


def run():
    df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={'X': ['8.12', '7.13', '-5.30', '3.21', '4.21', '3.14','8.65', '7.33', '-5.10', '3.01']
          })
    df['Y'] = df['X'].rolling(window=10, min_periods=1).apply(lambda x: count_pcnt(x)).apply(int)

    print(df)

Comment: X    Y
0   8.12  100
1   7.13  100
2  -5.30    0
3   3.21    0
4   4.21    0
5   3.14    0
6   8.65    0
7   7.33    0
8  -5.10    0
9   3.01    0

Comment: @COLDSPEED it appears the logic is breaking when it hits negative value

Comment: @user845405 Are you getting something different from me? Or are you saying my answer is incorrect?

Comment: @COLDSPEED yes i am getting different output than expected

Comment: @user845405 What version of pandas do you have? I am on 0.20. If you're on an older version, try updating first. This code works for me.

Comment: @COLDSPEED i am on version 0.20.2

Comment: I think `apply` int is not good idea, because lost floats - but if correct it your solution work.

Comment: @jezrael Actually the original question wanted the floats removed... OP added it back for some reason. Lol

Comment: @jezrael Thanks. I started learning pandas a couple of days back... Glad to know I'm doing something right :) Have made the correction.

Comment: @COLDSPEED df['Y'] = df['X'].apply(float).rolling(window=10, min_periods=1).apply(lambda x: count_pcnt(x)) work?  - no didn't

Answer (score 1):

It seems your data type for X is object instead of float. Try the following to see if it works.

```
 df['Y'] = (
    df.assign(X2=(df.X.astype(float)>0)).X2.rolling(window=10,min_periods=1)
      .apply(lambda x: sum(x)*100.0/len(x))
    )

df
Out[92]: 
       X           Y
0   8.12  100.000000
1   7.13  100.000000
2  -5.30   66.666667
3   3.21   75.000000
4   4.21   80.000000
5   3.14   83.333333
6   8.65   85.714286
7   7.33   87.500000
8  -5.10   77.777778
9   3.01   80.000000
```